# CSS for changing display of targeted sections

Tags: html, css

I have a combined local docs, group docs, and f.a.q. page I've been collating my documentation into. It's turning out very well and is easily updated and added to. There's a static navbar at the top with drop-down menus to navigate to parts of the document. Ideally, I'd like to hide all content other than that which is currently linked.

CSS:

```
<style>
  /* Block Elements */
    body { margin-bottom: 150px; background-color: white; }
    section { margin-left: 35px; }
  /* Select/Display Elements */
    section:not(#welcome) { display: none; }
    section:target { display: block; }
    ...
</style>
```

I've also tried:

```
section:active { display: block; }
section:focus { display: block; }
```

I've also tried to add `!important` to the `section:target { display: block !important; }` without success. In a simpler page without additional CSS I can get it to work, but I can't seem to get it to work with my full styles.

Suggestions?

Edit: A sample that seems to work as I'd like albeit with divs and not sections:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test Target Selector </title>
        <style>
            div { display: none; }
            div:target { display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="#1">1</a>
            <a href="#2">2</a>
            <a href="#3">3</a>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div id="1"> <h2> 1 </h2> <p> Content 1 </p> </div>
            <div id="2"> <h2> 2 </h2> <p> Content 2 </p> </div>
            <div id="3"> <h2> 3 </h2> <p> Content 3 </p> </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit2: Adding original full CSS and framework HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* Block Elements */
                body { font-family: "Antic Slab", "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 150px; background-color: white; }
                section { margin-left: 35px; }
            /* Select/Display Elements */
                section:not(#welcome) { display: none; }
                section:target { display: block; }
            /* Block Elements Continued */
                h1 { padding-top: 70px; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.4em; }
                h2 { padding-top: 70px; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.3em; }
                h3 { padding-top: 70px; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; }
                h4 { padding-top: 70px; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; }
                h5 { padding-top: 70px; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.0em; }
                p { text-align: justify; font-size: 1.0em; margin-right: 50px; }
                blockquote { margin: 15px 0 0 15px; margin-right: 50px; }
                blockquote p { padding-left: 15px; margin-right: 50px; }
                ol, ul, dl { margin: 15px 0 0 15px; margin-right: 50px; }
                li { padding: 5px; }
                dt { padding: 5px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }
                dd { padding: 5px; }
                img { display: none; border: 1px solid black; margin: 20px; padding: 0; width: 200px; }
            /* Inline Elements */
                a { text-decoration: none; color: blue; }
                a:hover { color: cyan; }
                code { font-family: monospace; font-size: 1.1em; }
                cite { color: darkgray; font-style: italic; }
                cite a { color: navy; }
                cite a:hover { color: cyan; }
                code { font-family: monospace; font-size: 1.10em; }
                blockquote.email { margin: 25px; border-left: 1px solid lightgray; }
            /* Classes */
                .email { border-left: 1px solid gray; }
                .lower-alpha { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }
                .outdated { color: red; }
                .indent { margin-left: 50px; }
                .center { text-align: center; }
                .indent { margin-left: 25px; }
                .no-wrap { white-space: nowrap; }
                .outdated { text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.9em; color: lightgray; }
            /* Main Navigation */
                nav ul { margin: 0 2px; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; list-style: none; background-color: black; padding: 0; text-align: center; }
                nav ul li { position: relative; float: left; color: white; background-color: black; display: inline-block; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 10px; font-size: 0.90em; }
                nav ul li:before { content: ""; }
                nav ul li a { color: white; margin: 0; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none; -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear; -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear; transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear; }
                nav ul li a:hover { color: white; }
                nav ul li:hover > a { background: black; }
            /* Drop-Down Navigation */
                nav ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
                nav ul ul, nav ul ul li ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 10px; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 99999; width: 180px; background: white; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; transition: opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear; }
                nav ul ul { top: 43px; left: 1px; }
                nav ul ul li ul { top: 0; left: 181px; }
                nav ul ul li { clear: both; width: 100%; border: 0 none; border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9; }
                nav ul ul li a { background: none; padding: 7px 15px; color: white; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; border: 0 none; float: left; clear: both; width: 150px; }
            /* Lists */
                ul { margin: 25px; list-style-type: none; }
                ul li { padding: 5px; font-size: 0.90em; text-align: justify; }
                ul li:before { content: "\2022"; }
                ol { margin: 25px; }
                ol li { padding: 5px; font-size: 0.90em; text-align: justify; }
                ol li.lower-alpha { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }
            /* Tables */
                table { margin: 25px 25px auto; border-collapse: collapse; }
                table caption { margin: 25px 0 25px 0; text-align: left; color: gray; }
                th, td { padding: 5px; border: 1px solid lightgray; vertical-align: center; }
                th { font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
                td { font-size: 0.8em; text-align: justify; white-space: nowrap; }
                td:hover { background-color: lightcyan; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul id="sitemap">
                <li class="h1"> <a href="#site_doc">Site Doc</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="h2"> <a href="#backup">Backup</a> </li>
                        <li class="h2"> <a href="#data">Data</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="h1"> <a href="#notes">Notes</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="h2"> <a href="#manual">Manual</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section id="welcome">
            <h1> Documentation Page </h1>
            <p> Welcome to the documentation page. </p>
            <p> This page is under development. </p>
        </section>
        <section id="site_doc">
            <h1> Site Doc </h1>
            <section id="backup">
                <h2> Backup </h2>
                <p> Backup procedures. </p>
            </section>
            <section id="data">
                <h2> Data </h2>
                <p> Data storage procedures. </p>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="notes">
            <h1> Notes </h1>
            <section id="manual">
                <h2> Manual </h2>
                <p> Manual. </p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code as well

Comment: Dynamically showing and hiding elements in most cases is impossible with CSS. You will need to use JavsScript to hide non-active sections and show the active only section.

Comment: @GhostPengy Actually, that's not true https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP

Comment: Added two edits. One with a sample code showing what I'd like and another with code I'm using. The same is using divs and not sections, but it _should_ work for both. Am I missing something in the nesting of sections in sections? As all the sections and their subsections will show up in the navbar, I was hoping to allow *any* targeted section to be displayed. If it's a parent section then all children sections should show. If just a child, then only the child section should show.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason your simplified example didn't work is because you had all sections wrapped in yet another section. Replace that wrapper with something else and it will work. As for the more generic problem with your other CSS, there's two ways of approaching it: either find out which rules are mixing up your custom CSS, or add more specific rules, e.g. CSS classes to your toggable sections.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test Target Selector </title>
        <style>
            section { display: none; }
            section:target { display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="#1">1</a>
            <a href="#2">2</a>
            <a href="#3">3</a>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <section id="1"> <h2> 1 </h2> <p> Content 1 </p> </section>
            <section id="2"> <h2> 2 </h2> <p> Content 2 </p> </section>
            <section id="3"> <h2> 3 </h2> <p> Content 3 </p> </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML is more semantically accurate with sections serving as a table of contents and allowing (eventually) XML export of the data. Is there a better (read: correct or more appropriate) way to target _all_ sections including sub-sections like: `section:target * { display: block; }` or `section > section:target { display: block; }`? I'm not entirely sure of the proper syntax to get all children to be included.

Comment: @phonedog365I think you are creating a problem where there really is none. In this case the simplest solution is the best. I would stick to different elements.